# regex for anything after a word except last character

Tags: regex

I need a regex for the last word after the word typedef, except for the last character. I know that `([^typedef]*)$` would give me the last word after typedef, but that would include the last character.

For example if I had the line `type long long integer;`, I want a regex that would give me `integer`, not `integer;`. If this helps, the last character will always be a semicolon.

Comment: Regex for which language?

Comment: I'm not sure really, I think xml. The file that I am editing is a sublime text .tmLanguage file.

Comment: `[^typedef]*` doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the regex that should work for you:

```
^typedef.*?\s(\w+)\s*;
```

Last word is available in matching group #1.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/Bzko9WIITw

Comment: @Bingo: Pls provide more examples as I'm not aware of all different combinations of `typedef` statement.

Comment: The expression seems to work in rubular, but it is not working in my code for some reason.

Comment: @OGH: That's why this question was asked you first in which language you want to implement it. Pls understand that every regex provider language/tool is different in some ways.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned that I am working with sublime text .tmLanguage file.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of `sublime text .tmLanguage`. I provided you a generic regex solution that will work on most regex platforms.

Comment: I appreciate your help anyways. Maybe I could modify your regex slightly and make it work.

Comment: Yes pls feel free to modify in anyway you need to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a period after your parenthesis to match 1 character but not capture it: ([^typedef]*).$

Comment: This only returns the 1 character before the semicolon.

Comment: The's because the 2nd to last character before the semicolon is `e`, which is in set of characters you don't want to match.